# Firebase, Cloud Firestore - SwiftUI display collection data in view

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have an app the uses Firebase for email/password authentication. When a user registers they register with an email, password, first name, and last name. This then creates a new document in my Cloud Firestore with the user's uid as the documentID. I have this successfully working, however, what is not working is displaying the user's data in a view.

I've written this fetchProfile function to retrieve the user's data from the Firestore. It prints the current users uid to the console.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore

struct UserProfile: Codable {
    var uid: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: UserProfile = UserProfile(uid: "", firstName: "", lastName: "")
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func createProfile(profile: UserProfile, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        do {
          let _ = try db.collection("users").document(profile.uid).setData(from: profile)
          completion(profile, nil)
        }
        catch let error {
          print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
          completion(nil, error)
        }
      }

      func fetchProfile(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
        db.collection("users").document(userId).addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard document.data() != nil else {
                print("Document data was empty")
                return
            }
            self.user = UserProfile(uid: document.get("uid") as? String ?? "", firstName: document.get("firstName") as? String ?? "", lastName: document.get("lastName") as? String ?? "")
            let user = try? documentSnapshot?.data(as: UserProfile.self)
            print(user?.uid ?? "")
        }
    }  
}
```

When I try to display the text in my view it comes up blank. Here is my code for the view.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct UserProfileView: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var userProfile: UserViewModel

  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Text(userProfile.user.uid)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("User \(userProfile.user.uid)")
        }
      } 
  }
```

[Cloud Firestore Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENsW.png)

I am new to swift so any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post a picture or print out of the data in the document?

Comment: @jnpdx Picture added to post

Comment: You aren't showing where you call `fetchProfile` -- are you sure it's on the same instance of `UserViewModel`?

Answer (score 1):

whenever you have a basic type that is not a string to display in a Text(), you can use this approach:

```
Text("\(userProfile.user.uid)")
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
userProfile.user.uid.toString()
```